# numpy error was occurred in Pypy condition

Tags: pypy

I ran the numpy code with pycharm in pypy.
I just printed np.array but did not work.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
```

This was all I did

I don't know that it is relevant, my python version is 3.9.2

The code below is error message that I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\pypy38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\pypy38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\pypy38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tnvlaos456/Desktop/practice/practice.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\pypy38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\pypy38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\practice\Scripts\pypy.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.0"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is confusing. You say

> python version is 3.9.2

but there is no such pypy released version.

NumPy prints out

> The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\practice\Scripts\pypy.exe"

but is loading NumPy 1.20.0 from `C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\pypy38\lib\site-packages`

So which is it: Python 3.9.2, PyPy3.8 from `C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\practice` or PyPy3.8 from `C:\Users\tnvlaos456\Desktop\pypy38` ?

How did you install PyPy and NumPy on the machine?

Comment: I installed python 3.9.2 on the python official website and pypy3.8 on the pypy official website. Numpy for pypy was installed by using PIP in the pypy folder after adding system path to 'This PC'